# Add team members to individual developer account

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

Is it possible to add team members to an individual developer account? The documentation says that it is possible for a company developer account; can you convert an individual to a company developer account?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert an individual account to a company account.  It does require that you have a registered business name, and will take about a week to be approved by apple.  An individual ccount has a team size of 1 -  you.

Comment: If you don't want to spend tons of money and time on opening a company if you don't need it yet, just log into the other person's Xcode account and pull in the certs. Much faster & cheaper than converting your account to a company. This is an unfortunate restriction by Apple that's making life harder.